# find the first appearance of a word in cells above in Excel

Tags: excel

Say I have a set of data looking like below. The first part is past results and I need to fill in future "balance after change". In particular, for the circled 3.5, I need to refer to the first balance before change corresponding to a. In particular, the last a in the cell above the current a. Then I need to read off the figure 3 and add on 0.5 change to get to 3.5. How to do so in Excel, please?

[image]

Comment: Why a? Can you show more examples? We need to see a pattern and one blank is not enough to determine the pattern. When blank, do you always want a? Do you want the cell above? The logic of what you are trying to do is not clear

Comment: @urdearboy I updated my question, I realise it's not correct before.

Comment: Will the change ever be negative?

Comment: Yes, it can be. All I need is a way to find where the first a above the current one and then read off the balance. Afterwards, it is simply adding the new change.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solution?

Comment: Sure thing, even though a formula would be better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the below formula is that you have to have the bottom of the lookup range stop before your last instance of `a`. You can do this in the formula with `OFFSET` looking to `balance before change` column, but the formula will get long fast

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$10)*($B$7=$A$2:$A$10))-1))
```